# re-base (firebase) query nested children and sort

Tags: javascript, firebase, ecmascript-6, firebase-realtime-database

I know that firebase recommends you denormalize your database structure... but what if you didn't listen properly...

Example:

> - users
> - - user1
> - - - foo
> - - - - baz
> - - - - bar
> - - - chats
> - - - - (huge JSON)
> - - user2
> - - - foo
> - - - - baz
> - - - - bar
> - - - chats
> - - - - (huge JSON)

`foo` and `chats` are my way of denormalizing data within each user..

Is it possible to query `users/*/foo` and sort it by `bar`?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot perform a query against a sibling property.